# How to reset partition drive letter

Tags: windows-7

I used Partition Magic software to reallocate partition space.

When I started Partition Magic, it asked to reset the partition drive letter and I responded "Yes" in the wizard. It changed the partition drive latter, but something went wrong and my disk partition is missing from my computer and I can neither access it with the drive letter nor see the drive icon.

I tried to change the partition drive letter using Windows 7 Storage Management, MiniTool Partition Wizard but could not reset the drive letter. I can see the drive in MiniTool Partition Wizard, Windows 7 Storage Management, but can not access it.

Answer (score 0):

try change it through here.... :

[image]

[image]

## EDIT :

```
      Click Start > type `diskpart`

      type `list volume`
      Type select volume 6 (replace 6 with the volume number assigned to the partition in question)
      Type assign letter Z (replace Z with the letter that you want to assign to it)
      When you look in Computer, you should be able to see your partition.
      Hope this helps
```

Comment: Thank You for fast reply...but as i say this method is not work for me...it is give me error that "Disk Management console view is not up to date"

Comment: @NileshPethani see my edit...........

Comment: List Volume command not showing my missing partitions(Actually before accident, i had three partition, now only can see C driven, D and E drives are missing....and D and E is not show in volume list

Comment: please upload some print screens

Comment: can you give me your email id...i can mail images to you

Comment: Post screen shots as edits to your question. Don't take solutions to email, otherwise it loses the effectiveness of the site

Comment: @Luke me ??????????

Comment: Yes, talking to you. Forgot to ping, sorry

Comment: @Royi....Sorry for asking email....but i am not able to post image with my question...superuser is not allow me to post image, because of i am new user.....but i can post the information about the partition

Partition - *:MyWork
Capacity -  97.66 GB
Used  - 28.82 GB
File System - NTFS
Type  - Primary
Status  - None

Answer (score 0):

Did not understand what is wrong from your post. Are you unable to change the drive letter? You have drive letter and cant access the volume ?

If i were you, read about "diskpart" and learn to use it.

Before changing volume that OS is sitting on (dangerous) - learn about what you are doing..

For your sake, if you tried to partition the windows OS drive, dont reboot because it might affect the boot folder and computer wont start with windows OS

Upload images of disk status: http://tinypic.com/
Read about using diskpart: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx