# Can I set up arbitrary filesystem redirection in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, folder-redirection

I am sitting in front of a Windows 7 machine that has no drive `Q:`.

Is it possible to arrange for accesses to `Q:\somedir` to be redirected to an arbitrary location on the existing filesystems (for example, `C:\Windows`)? I would especially like a "set it and forget it" option, if one exists.

I am assuming (although I have not tried it) that it is possible to use `SUBST` to mount an existing (empty, created for this purpose) folder as drive `Q:` and then `MKLINK /J` to create a directory symbolic link from `Q:\somedir` to wherever I want. However, this approach has a couple of drawbacks that I would like to avoid if possible:

1. The drive Q: will be visible in the system.
2. It is not as clean as I would like (removing the mounted folder will break it; a batch script needs to be manually added to the system startup).

Is there a better option? If there is none and I am forced to make compromises, what is the closest I could get to the ideal solution? Assume anything is up for discussion.

Comment: I don't understand why you want Q:\somedir to be visible, yet don't want Q:\ to be visible.

Comment: I tried what you said with `SUBST` and I could not CD through the symbolic link, but was able to from the SUBST'ed drive directly.

Comment: @rob: I would be fine with none of them being visible. My aim is to arrange for a suite of programs to look in `Q:\somedir` (which is possible but tedious) and allow the user to easily configure what the programs *really* look at by redirecting `Q:\somedir` (which will hopefully be much easier). I would prefer to redirect through something like `Q:\{insert-guid-here}` so that I have a very good chance of not stepping on any existing filesystem's toes.

Comment: @Jon I'm still not sure I understand. it sounds like you expect it to be accessible by your program without being visible on the filesystem. Is there a filesystem on some other platform which does what you want?

Comment: @rob: Not really, which is why I am OK with something "close enough". Although to be frank by now I have turned towards other types of solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Would `fsutil hardlink` do what you need?

Not sure if you make a hardlink from a `SUBST`'ed drive but you might be able to use an empty folder elsewhere in the filesystem.

A shame Windows doesn't have `mount --bind` like Linux.

Comment: I have not used `fsutil hardlink` in the past, but AFAIK hardlinks are only possible on files, not directories (the closest equivalent for directories being reparse points, `mklink /j`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't mount `Q:\Somedir` to a location, but it *is* possible to mount `Q:\` somewhere such that it is accessible but does not show up as `Q:\`, like `C:\mysecret`.

You need to open Disk Management and [Change the Drive Letters and Paths](https://superuser.com/a/502883/19841). You'd want to select your `Q:\` drive, unassign `Q:\`, and then assign it a path instead. This will cause the partition to be mounted at the path you designate instead of at the `Q:\` drive.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I am looking for, what I want to mount is not a partition but a directory.